# PHP: replace existing date in DB

Tags: php, database, insert-update

I'm trying to remove the current date and update it with a new date to show that it is the latest version. This happens without creating a new entry in the DB table. The below works to update other parts of the information but the date itself does not update once it has been initially inserted into the DB. I have been trying different things but nothing works quite right. any suggestions? Thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['productId'])) {
    $productId = $_POST['product'];
    $userId = $_POST['userId'];
    $teamplay = $_POST['teamplay'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if( $database->has('teamplays', [
        'AND' => [
            'productId' => $productId,
            'userId' => $userId
            
            
        ]
    ]) ) {
        $database->update('teamplays', [
            'teamplay' => $teamplay,
        ], [
            'productId' => $productId,
            'userId' => $userId
            


            
        ]);
    } else {
        $database->insert('teamplays', [
            'teamplay' => $teamplay,
            'productId' => $productId,
            'userId' => $userId,
            'teamplaydate' => $date
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your update sql queries? It doesn't look like you are passing the date variable to your update function. You can also you date=NOW() in your mysql query instead of creating the date in php

Comment: Add `'teamplaydate' => $date` to the array of columns in `$database->update()`.

Comment: thanks! @Barmar. I tried your suggestion, but I didn't notice it had 2 arrays for the $database->update().  I initially placed it in the second array of the $database->update(). I now tried the first array and it updated the dates correctly! Thanks again!

Comment: You're using your own custom database class, don't you know what the arguments are? I assume one of them is the columns to test in `WHERE`, and the other is the columns to update.